# How to get Grub 2.0 to see usb device on (USB 3) expresscard

Tags: grub, usb-3, expresscard, kexec

Im runing ubuntu off of a usb flash drive.

My laptop does not support booting from my expresscard (nor has any usb3 ports other than what i have added via my expresscard).

I'm using Grub 2.0x that Ubuntu 14.04 has installed onto my USB device which I am booting off of USB 2.0 ports.

I have another USB device plugged into my USB 3 expresscard. This has xenserver 5.6 installed on it.

I would like to boot to grub via my USB 2 and then load up xenserver off my USB 3 expresscard. However grub does not see the hard drive.

I've tried insmod ahci, ohci, and ata. With no luck. The USB drive is never seen off the USB 3 ports.

If I run lspci I do see the USB 3 host controller listed.

How can I boot off a USB 3 flash drive via my expresscard and grub?

I've read about dracut and saw some instructions for NEC and USB 3 by rebuilding initrd I believe. However Ubuntu doesn't work well with dracut. If I load it it breaks initramfs I believe which causes all sorts of chaos.

It is not a requirement that i use ubuntu. I was contemplating wiping out ubu and putting centos on just to try the dracut option. However I'm wondering if I can just solve this with grub. I have an uncle who said maybe I need to compile grub 2 with some driver modules but I didn't see any such options when I compiled it. I did see a way to install grub with a --install-modules=ata, ahci, etc option. I'm not sure how different this is from the regular insmod command, but choosing ahci broke my grub configs (due to relabeling my 'ls' drives to (ahci) devices).

Another option was to try and use kexec in an already booted kernel which sees the device, I didn't have much success with that however. System would kernel panic.

Answer (score 0):

Does your ExpressCard internal port get power on boot? Mine not, it only get power after an OS has loaded... at least it is hot-plug and hot-swap and works on Linux very well.

But no luck at boot since it has not power!

I am afraid the only way would be to load a micro-kernel that power it up (connect electricity) then do a cold reboot to another kernel that has ExpressCard support... both stored on any other medium that can be booted from by the BIOS / UEFI system.

I had give up trying some years ago.